# CSS Layouts: Div's within divs etc

Tags: css, layout, html

So my CSS layout was all fine until I wanted to add some into the content area of my web page.

What I'm trying to add into the content section is a wrapper box which contains a graph on the left and a bunch of little info boxes on the right, and potentially an info area underneath those two with 100% width of the content box.

But as soon as I add that in, it pushes my User Info div down below Content. =/ So I guess what's asking is how to create containers of divs within my content section that won't affect things like my sidebar?

Here's my code:

```
        <div id="wrapper">
                <div id="header"> </div><!-- #header-->
            <div id="nav"> </div>
            <div id="middle">
                <div id="container">
                    <div id="content"><!-- content -->
                        <div id='containerGraph'>
                           <div id='sngAnimals'></div>
                           <div id='graph'><img src='./lib/pChart2.1.1/examples/chartAnimalKillsPerDay.php' width='x' height='y' id='graphImg'/></div>
                           <div id='bottomCont'></div></div>
                    </div><!-- #content-->
                </div><!-- #container-->
                <div class="sidebar" id="sideLeft">
                    User info
                </div><!-- .sidebar#sideLeft -->
            </div><!-- #middle-->
        </div><!-- #wrapper -->
```

And the css:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    font: 12px/18px Arial, Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image:url('/mcimages/bg.png');
}
#wrapper {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
}

/* Middle
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#middle {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 0 100px;
    height: 1%;
    position: relative;

}
#middle:after {
    content: '.';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 0;
}
#container {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;

}
#content {
    padding: 10px 0 10px 195px;
    background: #666666;

}

#containerGraph {
border-style:solid;
border-width:5px;
width: 75%;
position:relative;

}

#graph {
width: 249px;
height: 210px;
border-style:solid;
border-width:5px;
position: relative;
float:left;


}

#sngAnimals {
width:50%;
height: 210px;
border-style:solid;
border-width:5px;
position: relative;
float:right;

}

#bottomCont{
position: relative;
clear:both;
}
 }

/* Sidebar Left
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#sideLeft {
    float: left;
    width: 175px;
    margin-left: -100%;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-right-color: black;
    border-right-width: 1px;
}

#friend {
    float: left;
    background: #B5AAFF;
    border:1px solid;
    position: relative;
    top:5px;
    left:0px;
    margin-left:10px;
    width:175px;
    height:175px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I've always hated this about many pre-built column layouts, they fail so ungracefully.

Comment: Heh, I figured how bad could a pre-built layout be? It's only a couple of columns with a head effectively, guess I was wrong. Any advice on how to fix it? CSS is NOT my strong point if you hadn't noticed.

Comment: It might be easy, might not.  Your question will *definitely* be easier if you can isolate the problem to a few lines of HTML/CSS.  To do that, remove everything that doesn't eliminate your problem, until you have the smallest example that is still broken.

Comment: l'm not sure I understand what you mean. I believe the problem lies within the CSS for the ContainerGraph div and it's contents. All I wish to do is have it contained within the content div without it affect the sidebar.

Comment: What I mean is that you could do the same thing I would be doing -- attempt to isolate the problem.  You've just posted your whole page here, and I'm not trying to be rude, but that's asking a lot.  A very common process all of us here follow when debugging is to whittle the problem down to the simplest possible reproduction and then change parameters on what's left until it works.

Comment: As, sorry, I didn't really know how much someone would need to fix a CSS problem, it seems when I change something, it always affects something else. ^^; I'm removed some of the redundant stuff to make it more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't close a div and your CSS had errors as well:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="nl" lang="nl">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="description" content="A short description." />
        <meta name="keywords" content="put, keywords, here" />
        <title>CraftLink</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="header">HEADER CONTENT</div><!-- #header-->
            <div id="nav">
                <a href="#">Nav item 1</a>
                <a href="#">Nav item 2</a>
                <a href="#">Nav item 3</a>
                <a href="#">Nav item 4</a>
            </div>
            <div id="middle">
                <div id="container">
                    <div class="sidebar" id="sideLeft">USER INFO GOES HERE.</div><!-- .sidebar#sideLeft -->
                    <div id="content"><!-- content -->
                        <div id='containerGraph'>
                            <div id='sngAnimals'></div>
                            <div id='graph'><img src='./lib/pChart2.1.1/examples/chartAnimalKillsPerDay.php' width='x' height='y' id='graphImg'/></div>
                            <div id='bottomCont'></div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- #content-->
                </div><!-- #container-->
            </div><!-- #middle-->
        </div><!-- #wrapper -->

        <!-- #footer -->
        <div id="footer">
            <h1>Footer Stuff</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    font: 12px/18px Arial, Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image:url('/mcimages/bg.png');
}
a {
    color: white;
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
p {
    margin: 0 0 18px
}
img {
    border: none;
}
input {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#wrapper {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
}


/* Header
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#header {
    height: 100px;
    background: #999999;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 200%;
}
#nav {
    height: 25px;
    background: #555555;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Middle
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#middle {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 0 100px;
    height: 1%;
    position: relative;

}
#middle:after {
    content: '.';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 0;
}
#container {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;

}
#content {
    padding: 10px 0 10px 195px;
    background: #666666;

}

#containerGraph {
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:5px;
    width: 75%;
    position:relative;
}

#graph {
    width: 249px;
    height: 210px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:5px;
    position: relative;
    float:left;
}

#sngAnimals {
    width:50%;
    height: 210px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:5px;
    position: relative;
    float:right;

}

#bottomCont{
    position: relative;
    clear:both;
}

/* Sidebar Left
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#sideLeft {
    float: left;
    width: 175px;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-right-color: black;
    border-right-width: 1px;
}

#friend {
    float: left;
    background: #B5AAFF;
    border:1px solid;
    position: relative;
    top:5px;
    left:0px;
    margin-left:10px;
    width:175px;
    height:175px;
}

/* Footer
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#footer {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: -100px auto 0;
    height: 100px;
    background: #BFF08E;
}

/* Progress bar
----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.meter-wrap{
    position: relative;
}

.meter-wrap, .meter-value, .meter-text {
    /* The width and height of your image */
    width: 155px; height: 30px;
}

.meter-wrap, .meter-value {
    background: #3D352A url(/path/to/your-image.png) top left no-repeat;
}

.meter-text {
    position: absolute;
    top:0; left:0;

    padding-top: 5px;

    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: You should use validators [HTML Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) and [CSS](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/)

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to go to a corner and cry for missing a curly brace.

I think the unclosed DIV was a typo when I put it into SO so at least that's....something.

Comment: Don't feel bad, this gets everyone in the beginning, and will come back to haunt you, even after you become an expert. Also, it's actually pretty funny. Every-time I have a problem with HTML here at my job, the Design Guy always goes, "Did you close the DIV?" and I will respond, "Darn, that was it!" Turns out that was half the problem here.